# Create PHP array from file

Tags: php, arrays, excel, csv, drupal

I'm developing Drupal module to check if there is allowed value in the particular field of the form. If there is, the user is able to submit the form, if not the user gets error message.

There is the code I'm using:

```
  my_module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
      // Add one more validation.
      $form['#validate'][] = '_my_module_name_custom_form_valition';
    }
  }

  function _my_module_name_custom_form_valition($form, $form_state) {
   // $form_state holds value for submitted fields.
   if(!in_array($allowed_values,$form_state['values']['your_form_field']) {
      form_set_error('your_form_field',t('Entered value is not allowed.'));
   }
  }
```

I need to add the variable '$allowed_values' in this code that is the array. The problem is that I have to have 1500 strings in this array, and I have all those strings in Excel file in one column in cells one below the other.

My question is can I export the .CSV file from Excel and to convert the values from that file in PHP array I mentioned above ($allowed_values)?

Every suggestion how to achieve this is welcome.

Comment: Fetch the content of this CSV file using `file_get_contents` and `explode` it using the line delimiter. Post the exact format/output of the CSV file for a concrete code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a function `fgetcsv` that can be used to read lines from a CSV file. So you can do something like:

```
$allowed_values = array();
if ( ( $handle = fopen( "data.csv", "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
    while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        // $data now contains a row of values from the CSV file
        // Add to $allowed_values
    }
}
fclose( $handle );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_map for this. Worked for me at least.

```
$values = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

alternately first load the file:

```
 $file = file_get_contents("file.csv");

 $values = array_map('str_getcsv', $file);
```